# Run Matlab function (*.m) in subdir / path of file stands in variable

Tags: matlab, function, arguments

I want to run a function "folder/test.m". This path stands in a variable "var_path". How do I run the function with parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [system command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html).

For example:

```
sys_com = ['C:\path\to\matlab.exe ', var_path, ' ', parameter1, ' ', parameter2];
system(sys_com);
```

First line creates a command as a string (parameters should be strings). Second line executes that string.

Comment: Interesting idea. Does this start another instance of Matlab?

Comment: @Deve: yes, a new instance

Comment: In that case it creates quite some computational overhead. Additionally, parsing the stdout to get the function result can become complex and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

you can either change dir to `var_path` and then run `test` as a regular funciton. 
Alternatively, you can add `var_path` to your path and run `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab does not allow including function files (like in C/C++, for example). There are two possbilities to achieve something similar:

1. Change the folder during script execution
2. Change the search path to make the function file visible to the Matlab interpreter

Example for 1:

```
cur_dir = pwd; % save current directory
cd(var_path);  % change to directory containing the function
test(a, b);
cd(pwd);       % change back to original directory
```

This can have unwanted side effects of course, e.g. if your script relies on other files in the current directory or if you write to files.

Example for 2:

```
cur_path = path(); % save current path variable
addpath(var_path); % add function path to Matlab path
test(a, b);
setpath(cur_path); % restore original path variable
```